# Security risk in a frame login

Tags: security, frame

I'm developing a simple login that is shown in other site pages by a javascript.

The first time, my script loaded the login page as a content div injected into the page but i realised that if the "other site page" the one from i open my login, has a simple javascript function  the "listen" what i insert into username and password field it could be a security risk for my users.

Now i change my way, and i'm thinking to open the login page with a script that "inject" a frame into a page, using fancybox for example.

Now my question: Could this way be secure ? or the "other site page" could use some script to catch the account data that my user insert into a frame login ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The model of trusted-iframe untrusted-parent-page cannot be made secure.

As an iframe you are completely at the mercy of the parent page. Apart from the problems of clickjacking attacks being used to subvert interaction with the frame contents, there's also the issue that the user being asked to login has no way to know that the iframe is genuine.

As far as the user can see, the login form is part of the site whose address is in the address bar; although some browsers do provide the ability to inspect an iframe and verify its source, this is not a course of action you could reasonably expect a user to follow every time.

If you are putting sensitive content (such as a login form) in an iframe you (and the user) must completely trust the including site, whose name appears in the address bar. If you don't, then you will need a different model. Typically: redirecting the user through a login page, like in OpenID, or opening a pop-up.

There are compromises you can do to avoid switching page: for example if the user has a cookie then you might skip the login form, or provide a simpler login form that asks for an incomplete or different credential to the one requested on the full login form. (The idea being that if the including site does intercept the credential in some way, it's not enough to do a full login; including sites do not get to touch the included site's cookies.)

Comment: thank you for you answer. it was a good idea ask before act. :)